# jsch-->Not able to connect from unix jump server to another unix servers using java

Tags: java, unix, jsch

I am not able to connect secured server one unix server to another unix server.From putty by ssh i am able to connect easily but i am geeting below error when connet from jsch.

successful putty Steps->connect server1 in putty->on successful->Connect server2 using "ssh user@ip"

**jsch steps-->**

Connected session1-->one server connected //comment-->running command on server 1 to connect other server

**Error:-**
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
ksh: changeme:  not found
exit-status: 127

**Jsch sample program-->**

java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

```
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.setKnownHosts("C://known_hosts.txt");
         session=jsch.getSession(user1, server1, 22);
        session.setPassword(password1);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected session1");

        String command ="ssh"+"  "+"user@ip;"+"password" ; 

         channel=session.openChannel("exec");   
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);   
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print("server 1"+new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channel.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
         channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding important part of answer:-

```
      JSch jsch = new JSch();
      jsch.setKnownHosts("C:/My Program Files/eclipse/workspace/StatusTracker/known_hosts.txt");
     // jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHostLoc);
      //Jump server connection session started
      jumpServerSession = jsch.getSession(userid, jump server ip/hostname, 22);
      jumpServerSession.setPassword(jump server password);
      java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
      config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
      jumpServerSession.setConfig(config);
      jumpServerSession.connect();
     System.out.println("The session has been established to "+jump server userid+"@"+jump server name);

        int assinged_port = jumpServerSession.setPortForwardingL(0, other server ip, 22);
        System.out.println("portforwarding: "+
                           "localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+other server ip+":"+22);
        //Main server connection session started
        targetServerSession =  jsch.getSession(fileBO.getServerUserId(), "127.0.0.1", assinged_port);
        targetServerSession.setHostKeyAlias(other server ip);
        targetServerSession.setPassword(other server password);
        java.util.Properties config1 = new java.util.Properties();
        config1.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        targetServerSession.setConfig(config1);
        targetServerSession.connect();


        channel = targetServerSession.openChannel("sftp");
        channel = targetServerSession.openChannel("exec");

//command want to execute on dest server
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("pwd"); 

          channel.setInputStream(null);
    InputStream in11=channel.getInputStream();
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);   
    channel.connect();
    byte[] tmp1=new byte[1024];
    while(true){
        while(in11.available()>0){
            int i1=in11.read(tmp1, 0, 1024);
            if(i1<0)break;
            System.out.print(new String(tmp1, 0, i1));
        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
    }

    } catch (final JSchException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Did this work? I am also trying to implement similar thing. I have 2 doubts: `1. int assinged_port = jumpServerSession.setPortForwardingL(0, other server ip, 22);` :- here why are we giving the Local Port as 0?? Shouldn't it be 22 instead. Since, this Local port is the port of the Jump-Server            `2. targetServerSession =  jsch.getSession(fileBO.getServerUserId(), "127.0.0.1", assinged_port);` :- Here, while creating the main session with 3rd server, we are passing IP as LocalHost. Why ?? . Please correct my understanding is incorrect. I am new to ssh connections.

Comment: What is `fileBO`........ There's like 6 undeclared variables in your answer, how the heck is this accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing port forwarding, you can simply use channel.setPty(true) before connecting. After this you can provide the password using outPutStream.